# lwjgl java game will run but not actually launch past start up screen

Tags: java, jar, lwjgl

okay so bassically when I export my game it will run and open a jframe but for some reason wont move on to my next game scene and I think it errors where its supposed to play a sound. Thanks in advance. Dwain. Also i have tried jar splice and jar matie. Nothing seems to work.

Main class

```
package com.DwainEdwards.main;


import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

import com.DwainEdwards.main.Screen;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1550691097823471818L;

    public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;

    private Menu menu;
    private Handler handler;
    private HUD hud;
    private Hudp2 hudp2;
    private HUDP1 hudp1;
    public ID id;
    private Spawn spawner;
    private Spawn2 spawner2;
    private Screen screen;
    private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    private int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer())
            .getData();
    static Texture tex;

    public void init() {
        tex = new Texture();
        screen = new Screen(WIDTH, HEIGHT, new SpriteSheet("/sprite_sheet.png"));
    }

    public static Texture getInstance() {
        return tex;
    }

    public enum STATE {
        Intro, Menu, Play, Singleplayer, GameOver,
        easy, Game, Game2, Game3, Level1C, Level2C,
        Level3C, Hardcore, survive, local, Help,
        Credits, Character, Skin, Player1wins, Player2wins
    };

    public static float clamp(float var, float min, int max) {
        if (var >= max)
            return var = max;
        else if (var <= min)
            return var = min;
        else
            return var;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Game();
    }

    public STATE gameState = STATE.Intro;

    public Game() {
        new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "the Epic Game", this);
        handler = new Handler();
        menu = new Menu(this, handler);
        this.addMouseListener(menu);
        hud = new HUD();
        hudp2 = new Hudp2();
        this.addKeyListener(new KeyInput(handler));
        spawner = new Spawn(handler, hud);
        spawner2 = new Spawn2(handler, hudp1);

        AudioPlayer.Load();

        new Random();
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        running = true;
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        try {
            thread.join();
            running = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.requestFocus();
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double nsPerTick = 1000000000D / 60D;

        int ticks = 0;
        int frames = 0;

        long lastTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double delta = 0;

        init();

        while (running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / nsPerTick;
            lastTime = now;
            boolean shouldRender = true;

            while (delta >= 1) {
                ticks++;
                tick();
                delta -= 1;
                shouldRender = true;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (shouldRender) {
                frames++;
                render();
            }
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimer >= 1000) {
                lastTimer += 1000;
                System.out.println(ticks + " ticks, " + frames + " frames");
                frames = 0;
                ticks = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    private void tick() {
        handler.tick();
        if (gameState == STATE.Game) {
            hud.tick();
            spawner.tick();

            if (hud.HEALTH <= 0) {
                hud.HEALTH = 100;
                handler.clearEnemys();
                AudioPlayer.getSound("gosound").play();
                gameState = STATE.GameOver;
            } else if (hud.level == 10) {
                HUD.HEALTH = 100;
                handler.clearEnemys();
                AudioPlayer.getSound("victory").play();
                gameState = STATE.Level1C;
            }
    }else if (gameState == STATE.Intro) { 
        menu.tick();
    } else if (gameState == STATE.Game2) {
        hud.tick();
            spawner.tick();
            if (HUD.HEALTH <= 0) {
                HUD.HEALTH = 100;
                handler.clearEnemys();
                gameState = STATE.GameOver;
            } else if (HUD.level == 20) {
                HUD.HEALTH = 100;
                handler.clearEnemys();
                AudioPlayer.getSound("victory").play();
                gameState = STATE.Level2C;
            }
        } else if (gameState == STATE.Game3) {
            hud.tick();
            spawner.tick();
            if (HUD.HEALTH <= 0) {
                HUD.HEALTH = 100;
                handler.clearEnemys();
                gameState = STATE.GameOver;
            } else if (HUD.level == 30) {
                HUD.HEALTH = 100;
                handler.clearEnemys();
                gameState = STATE.Level3C;

                if (HUD.HEALTH <= 0) {
                    HUD.HEALTH = 100;
                    handler.clearEnemys2();
                    gameState = STATE.GameOver;
            }
            } else if (gameState == STATE.Menu) {
                menu.tick();
            } else if (gameState == STATE.Help) {
                menu.tick();
            } else if (gameState == STATE.GameOver) {
                menu.tick();
            } else if (gameState == STATE.Level1C) {
                menu.tick();
            } else if (gameState == STATE.Level2C) {
                menu.tick();
            } else if (gameState == STATE.Credits) {
                menu.tick();
            } else if (gameState == STATE.Character) {
                menu.tick();
            } else if (gameState == STATE.Play) {
                menu.tick();
            } else if (gameState == STATE.Singleplayer) {
                menu.tick();
            } else if (gameState == STATE.local) {
                hudp1.tick();
                hudp2.tick();
                spawner2.tick();

                if (HUD.HEALTH <= 0) {
                    HUD.HEALTH = 100;
                    Hudp2.HEALTH = 100;
                    handler.clearEnemys2();
                    gameState = STATE.Player1wins;
                } else if (Hudp2.HEALTH <= 0) {
                    HUD.HEALTH = 100;
                    Hudp2.HEALTH = 100;
                    handler.clearEnemys2();
                    gameState = STATE.Player2wins;
                }
            }
        } else if (gameState == STATE.Skin) {
            menu.tick();
        } else if (gameState == STATE.Player1wins) {
            menu.tick();
        } else if (gameState == STATE.Player2wins) {
            menu.tick();
        }
    }

    private void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        screen.render(pixels, 0, WIDTH);

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);

        handler.render(g);
        if (gameState == STATE.Game) {
            hud.render(g);

        } else if (gameState == STATE.Game2) {
            hud.render(g);
        } else if (gameState == STATE.Game3) {
            hud.render(g);

        } else if (gameState == STATE.local) {
            hud.render(g);
            hudp2.render(g);
        } else if (gameState == STATE.Menu) {
            menu.render(g);

        } else if (gameState == STATE.Help) {
            menu.render(g);

        } else if (gameState == STATE.Credits) {
            menu.render(g);

        } else if (gameState == STATE.GameOver) {

            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

            Font fnt = new Font("arial", 1, 50);
            Font fnt2 = new Font("arial", 1, 30);
            Font fnt3 = new Font("arial", 1, 15);

            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRect(250, 350, 150, 64);

            g.setFont(fnt);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawString("Game Over", 200, 100);

            g.setFont(fnt3);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawString("You have lost with a score of: " + hud.getScore(),
                    160, 200);
            g.drawString("You lost on level: " + hud.getLevel(), 160, 250);

            g.setFont(fnt2);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawString("Try Again", 260, 390);

            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(250, 350, 150, 64);
        } else if (gameState == STATE.Level1C) {
            Font fnt = new Font("arial", 1, 50);
            Font fnt2 = new Font("arial", 1, 30);
            Font fnt3 = new Font("arial", 1, 15);

            g.setFont(fnt);
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.drawString("Stage Complete!", 110, 100);

            g.setFont(fnt3);
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.drawString("You have won with a score of: " + hud.getScore(),
                    160, 200);
            g.drawString("You won on level: " + hud.getLevel(), 160, 250);

            g.setFont(fnt2);
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.drawString("Next Level", 260, 390);

            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.drawRect(250, 350, 170, 64);

        } else if (gameState == STATE.Level3C) {
            Font fnt = new Font("arial", 1, 50);
            Font fnt2 = new Font("arial", 1, 30);
            Font fnt3 = new Font("arial", 1, 15);

            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRect(250, 350, 170, 64);

            g.setFont(fnt);
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.drawString("Stage 3 Complete!", 110, 100);

            g.setFont(fnt3);
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.drawString("You have won with a score of: " + hud.getScore(),
                    160, 200);
            g.drawString("You won on level: " + hud.getLevel(), 160, 250);

            g.setFont(fnt2);
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.drawString("Next Level", 260, 390);

            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.drawRect(250, 350, 170, 64);
        } else if (gameState == STATE.Level2C) {
            Font fnt = new Font("arial", 1, 50);
            Font fnt2 = new Font("arial", 1, 30);
            Font fnt3 = new Font("arial", 1, 15);

            g.setFont(fnt);
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.drawString("Stage 2 Complete!", 110, 100);

            g.setFont(fnt3);
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.drawString("You have won with a score of: " + hud.getScore(),
                    160, 200);
            g.drawString("You won on level: " + hud.getLevel(), 160, 250);

            g.setFont(fnt2);
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.drawString("Next Level", 260, 390);

            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.drawRect(250, 350, 170, 64);
        } else if (gameState == STATE.Character) {
            Font fnt = new Font("arial", 1, 50);
            Font fnt2 = new Font("arial", 1, 30);

            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRect(25, 370, 150, 64);

            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRect(25, 130, 150, 64);

            g.setFont(fnt);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawString("Player", 40, 80);

            g.setFont(fnt2);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawString("Back", 60, 410);

            g.setFont(fnt2);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawString("Skin", 65, 170);

            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(25, 370, 150, 64);

            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(25, 130, 150, 64);
        } else if (gameState == STATE.Play) {
            Font fnt = new Font("arial", 1, 50);
            Font fnt2 = new Font("arial", 1, 30);

            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRect(236, 370, 150, 64);

            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRect(236, 270, 150, 64);

            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRect(236, 170, 150, 64);

            g.setFont(fnt);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawString("Play", 255, 70);

            g.setFont(fnt2);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawString("Back", 275, 410);

            g.setFont(fnt2);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawString("Solo", 275, 210);

            g.setFont(fnt2);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawString("Local", 265, 310);

            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(236, 370, 150, 64);

            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(236, 270, 150, 64);

            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(236, 170, 150, 64);
        } else if (gameState == STATE.Singleplayer) {
            Font fnt = new Font("arial", 1, 50);
            Font fnt2 = new Font("arial", 1, 25);

            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRect(248, 100, 120, 50);

            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRect(248, 169, 120, 50);

            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRect(248, 240, 120, 50);

            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRect(248, 310, 120, 50);

            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRect(236, 370, 150, 64);

            g.setFont(fnt);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawString("Solo", 255, 70);

            g.setFont(fnt2);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawString("Back", 275, 410);

            g.setFont(fnt2);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawString("Baby", 275, 134);

            g.setFont(fnt2);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawString("Classic", 265, 200);

            g.setFont(fnt2);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawString("Hardcore", 253, 272);

            g.setFont(fnt2);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawString("Survival", 257, 344);

            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(248, 100, 120, 50);

            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(248, 169, 120, 50);

            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(248, 240, 120, 50);

            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(248, 310, 120, 50);

            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(236, 370, 150, 64);
        } else if (gameState == STATE.Intro) { 
            Font fnt = new Font("Arial", 1, 50);

            g.setFont(fnt);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawString("The Epic Game", 0, 50);

            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(232, 232, 32, 32);

            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(332, 332, 16, 16);
        } else if (gameState == STATE.Skin) {
            Font fnt = new Font("arial", 1, 20);

            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRect(540, 400, 90, 45);

            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(540, 400, 90, 45);

            g.setFont(fnt);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawString("Back", 563, 432);

            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(32, 32, 32, 32);

            g.setColor(Color.orange);
            g.fillRect(64, 32, 32, 32);

            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(96, 32, 32, 32);

            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(128, 32, 32, 32);

            g.setColor(Color.yellow);
            g.fillRect(160, 32, 32, 32);

            g.setColor(Color.magenta);
            g.fillRect(192, 32, 32, 32);

            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillRect(224, 32, 32, 32);

            g.drawImage(tex.player[0], 256, 32, null);

            g.drawImage(tex.player[1], 288, 32, null);

            g.drawImage(tex.player[2], 320, 32, null);

            g.setColor(Color.pink);
            g.fillRect(352, 32, 32, 32);

            g.drawImage(tex.player[3], 384, 32, null);

            g.drawImage(tex.player[4], 416, 32, null);
        }
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }
}
```

AudioPlayer class

```
package com.DwainEdwards.main;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.newdawn.slick.Music;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.Sound;

public class AudioPlayer {

    public static Map<String, Sound> soundMap = new HashMap<String, Sound>();
    public static Map<String, Music> musicMap = new HashMap<String, Music>();

    public static void Load() {
        try {
            musicMap.put("music", new Music("com/DwainEdwards/sounds/Menu.ogg"));
            soundMap.put("gosound", new Sound("com/DwainEdwards/sounds/GameOver.ogg"));
            soundMap.put("punch", new Sound("com/DwainEdwards/sounds/Punch.ogg"));
            soundMap.put("victory", new Sound("com/DwainEdwards/sounds/Victory.ogg"));
            soundMap.put("cssound", new Sound("com/DwainEdwards/sounds/CSVO.ogg"));
            soundMap.put("white", new Sound("com/DwainEdwards/sounds/WHITE.ogg"));
            soundMap.put("orange", new Sound("com/DwainEdwards/sounds/ORANGE.ogg"));
            soundMap.put("red", new Sound ("com/DwainEdwards/sounds/RED.ogg"));
            soundMap.put("black", new Sound ("com/DwainEdwards/sounds/BLACK.ogg"));
            soundMap.put("yellow", new Sound ("com/DwainEdwards/sounds/YELLOW.ogg"));
            soundMap.put("purple", new Sound ("com/DwainEdwards/sounds/PURPLE.ogg"));
            soundMap.put("hitler", new Sound ("com/DwainEdwards/sounds/HITLER.ogg"));
            soundMap.put("disturbed", new Sound ("com/DwainEdwards/sounds/DISTURBED.ogg"));
            soundMap.put("mario", new Sound ("com/DwainEdwards/sounds/MARIO.ogg"));
            soundMap.put("blue", new Sound ("com/DwainEdwards/sounds/BLUE.ogg"));
        } catch (SlickException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Music getMusic(String key) {
        return musicMap.get(key);
    }

    public static Sound getSound(String key) {
        return soundMap.get(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're getting errors, please post the stack trace. And also, try to put only the relevant part of your code, not the whole thing.

Comment: it is not the whole thing and there is no error its completely speculation. It after the export. In the code I dont seem to get errors I will try running with console
update -

Comment: java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents<EventDispatchThread.java:93>
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run<EventDispatchThread.java:82>
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.newdawn.slick.SlickException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass<URLClassLoader.java:381>
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass<ClassLoader.java:424>
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass<Launcher.java:331>
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass<ClassLoader.java:357>
... 23 more